# How to list the packages from 90-updates-available?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, security, software-updates

The script `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available` provides a summary of system updates, for example:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available  
281 packages can be updated.
209 updates are security updates.
```

Is there any way to list this 209 security updates?

Apparently, this script comes from `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` but I can't find any clue about where is it taking the values.

I thought the list could be taken from the command `apt list --upgradable`, but I don't find a coincidence between the number of packages when doing `grep` with the word "security":

```
apt list --upgradable | grep security | wc -l
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
184
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question in full, but you can see the packages names by running `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p` (this is the tool which generates the `motd` snippet). That however doesn’t separate security updates from other updates.